# Getting an update column's new value in a row in rethinkdb

Tags: rethinkdb

I am trying to get and update a column in a row in rethinkdb using a similar statement.

```
User.get_table() \
               .get(self.id) \
               .update(return_changes = True, 
                 {'reward_amount' :r.row['reward_amount'].default(0)+amount}) \
               .run(User.get_conn())
```

I am getting new value by passing return_changes=True, but is it possible to write a anonymous function that just returns new value as a int instead of array of old and new objects (which is what return_changes=True does)

Answer (score 0):

You can write `update(...)['changes'][0]['new_val']['reward_amount']`.